# Python string comparison fails but if accepts

Tags: python, string

Given:

```
if parse_rec[i] != col_data:
    parse_rec[i] = col_data
    data_changed = True
    print str(i)
    print str(parse_rec[i])
    print str(col_data)
    print type(parse_rec[i])
    print type(col_data)
    print len(parse_rec[i])
    print len(col_data)
    print parse_rec[i] != col_data
```

I get:

```
10
1037864
1037864
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
7
7
False
```

If I change the test to:

```
if str(parse_rec[i]) != str(col_data):
```

It works as expected and the 'if' condition fails (they are equal) and nothing prints.  What is the str() doing?  Why do I need it?  Can I not trust any string comparisons in Python?

I have verified it.  There are no tabs in my file.

Comment: *"Can I not trust any string comparisons in Python?"* - it sounds more like the problem was that **you weren't doing string comparisons**. You certainly can't expect e.g. `1 == '1'`, Python is strongly typed.

Comment: Could share the contents of `parse_rec` ?

Comment: Firstly, your `print`s would be more helpful if you show us what `parse_rec[i]` is *before* you assign it to `col_data`. In fact, I bet if you do all those prints *before* assigning, you might see an answer. Secondly, it makes no sense to ask if string comparisons fail, when your example shows that *some* comparison fails, but string comparison doesn't.

Comment: if you look a little closer, jonsharpe, you'll see that I print the types of each.

Comment: @BlakeMcBride you print them *after* you set it. Perhaps `col_data` is a string, but before assigning, `parse_rec[i]` isn't a string.

Comment: You know `!=` means **not** equal, right? `parse_rec[i] != col_data` is `False`, which is what you'd expect, because `7 == 7` (also `'7 == '7'`). Your question is extremely confusing. What's the point in checking all of that *after* `parse_rec[i] = col_data`?

Comment: type(parse_rec) ->  <type 'pyodbc.Row'>

Comment: @BlakeMcBride and if you look a little closer, you'll see that you've replaced the original `parse_rec[i]` before you do so.

Comment: Thanks, dwanderson.  You are correct, my assignment was hiding all of my tests.  If I print beofr the assignment the problem is clear.  One is a string and the other is a datetime.  Problem solved.  Thanks for the help - everyone!

Comment: @BlakeMcBride remove this "parse_rec[i] = col_data" from the second line and edit your question with the new output

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if e.g. `parse_rec[i]` originally contained the number `10` while `col_data` contained the string `'10'`. `str` converts any Python object to a string representation; converting both of them (with one already being a string) would make them equal.

Answer (score -1):

Your two data are strings and can be safely compared with the `==` operator.

What `str()` does:

> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object. For strings, this returns the string itself.

If you had an integer and a string, `str()` becomes necessary:

```
print 123 == '123' # false
print 123 is '123' # false
print str(123) == '123' # true
print '123' == '123' # true
print '123' is '123' # false
```